# jQuery interface for finding location in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Can anyone please suggest any jQuery script for capturing google map location from the user?

To be more specific...
I want website user to locate their addresses online using Google map so that I can store address' location in the db. It should be very simple approach with following steps..

- User provides the address in the address field.
- Based on the address provided, google map find the most suitable address.
- User correct the address if required.
- User clicks on save button, which in turn stores the located address in the db...

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this plugin will help you http://code.google.com/p/locationpicker/
Looks like it does everything you want